# KDE Sometimes Glitches On Wakeup

Tags: nvidia, xorg, kde

Well, a picture is work 1k words:

[image]

Looks bad, huh?

I am using the <s>331-updates</s> latest 331.67 drivers from NVidia's website on a Dell Latitude e6400. Everything else is up-to-date. This only happens when I resume from sleep, or I switch to a VT and back. It also doesn't ALWAYS happen, which I find odd. Graphics Card: Nvidia Quadro NVS160M

UPDATE AFTER TESTING: This problem only exists with KDE (specifically QT). I can go into Unity or Mint or any non QT-based GUI and it works perfectly with no resume errors.

UPDATE: This only happens when I use KWin (and KDE). I have upgraded to 14.04 and the problem is not occurring as frequently. Also, sometimes this effect doesn't happen, but instead the top menu bar simply goes out of focus with the rest of the screen goes blank.

Comment: Why are you using the latest drivers? And what card do you have?

Comment: because 304 gives me terrible problems.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem like they're the only ones that give you terrible problems :D How do you usually resolve this when it happens?

Comment: Reboot. Or restart the KDM service from TTY.

Comment: Hmm. What graphics card do you have? How many driver options do you have?

Comment: nVidia Quatro NVS160M (i think)  and 304, 304-updates, 319, 319-updates

Comment: Try 304-updates please.

Comment: I have tried all the available drivers to me and this bug persists. I have not yet tried the Noveau one, though.

Comment: Well try that one then ;)

Comment: installed noveau, no chance to test yet.

Comment: Tested Noveau driver, it destroys my gaming system, overheats my PC hourly, AND still crashes. Going to plain 319.

Comment: Still no further updates. I am now getting worried about this bug

Comment: Have you tried turning some of the fancy KDE features off? Do you have the nvidia x server settings app installed?

Comment: settings app yes, fancy features off. still exists.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help anymore since I don't use KDE.. You don't have OpenGL or anything like that enabled do you? I can't run KDE because of my nvidia card too

Comment: opengl, i think so. how would i check?

Comment: That's one thing I don't know..

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.maketecheasier.com/optimize-kde-desktop-effects/

Comment: edited question.

Comment: Have you tried a quick Alt + Shift + F12 to toggle desktop effects? and then try it again to turn em on again? What about switching to a virtual terminal with Ctrl+ Alt + F1 and then Ctrl + Alt + F7 to return?

Comment: I have tried the virtual terminal method, and it does not work. I am not sure though if Alt+Shift+F12 works yet. Lemme try that if it fails again, just updated to the 331.67 drivers.

Comment: Alt+Shift+F12 DOES NOT WORK.

Comment: same on macbook pro 5.4. with kubuntu 14.04 Don't know how to fix

Comment: try changing the way BIOS sleeps/wakes, i had this problem with KDE alot, i ended up having to do that, my stupid motherboard had a glitchy bios that didnt repost the video on wakeup so it had some problems, then I upgraded and things were fine once it got a repost... this could be your problem, also I've noticed having widgets on a screensaver can cause(other) problems too.

Comment: despite the problem: That looks like an AWESOME screen-saver.

Comment: @Mark, It gets very very flashy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact same bug was happening to me recently.  Dell XPS M1330 with NVIDIA 8400M GS on Ubuntu Saucy with KDE from kubuntu-ppa/backports.

I found that simply toggling Desktop Effects off and on fixed it.  The default key is `Alt+Shift+F12`.  Also, if you leave Desktop Effects off, it doesn't happen.  I usually leave them off because it lets my laptop run a little cooler.

Hopefully future upgrades to KDE or the driver will fix this.  I haven't upgraded this laptop to Trusty yet.

Comment: Not for me. Someone recommended that in the comments, to no avail.

Comment: I guarantee you that if you turn off Desktop Effects, this will go away. The default hotkey is indeed `Alt+Shift+F12`. You can also go to `System Settings/Desktop Effects` and turn off `Enable desktop effects at startup`.  You can also go to the `Advanced` tab and try changing the `Compositing type`.  If none of the OpenGL choices work, you can set it to `XRender` and it will run on the CPU instead of the GPU, which should also workaround this bug, but with less performance.  If somehow none of that works, edit `~/.kde/share/config/kwinrc` and change `Enabled` under `[Compositing]` to `false`.

Comment: It does not. It involves NVidia's dynamic system, which QT doesn't support. It's QT that is causing the problem, not any desktop effects.

Comment: What do you mean, "dynamic system"?  What do you mean that Qt doesn't support it?  KDE and Qt use OpenGL, which is supported by the nvidia driver.  There are always some hardware-specific quirks, which is why KWin has its own model-specific blacklist.  But what you said doesn't make any sense.  If you turn off desktop effects, it will use standard 2D X stuff, not 3D OpenGL stuff, and this bug will not happen.  It can't.  You can see in your screenshot how it's drawing triangles, obviously in 3D compositing mode.  Turn off compositing and this bug cannot happen.

Comment: I tried, still fails with the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

***This for some reason no longer works!***

I finally managed to figure it out by following the instructions of a few guides. I'm not sure what part was the magic bullet though.

1. Run the command `nvidia-settings -a InitialPixmapPlacement=2 -a GlyphCache=1`
2. Add the  content at post bottom to the Device options file in xorg.conf (back up!!)
3. Run command `pm-suspend --quirk-save-pci` to test sleep and restore. If it works successfully,
4. Add `pm-suspend --quirk-save-pci` to the `/var/cache/pm-utils/last_known_working.quirkdb` file.
5. Reboot

---

Stuff to add to xorg.conf:

```
Option "PixmapCacheSize" "1000000"
Option "AllowSHMPixmaps" "0"
Option "OnDemandVBlankInterrupts" "True"
```